# Keyboard.h not found

Tags: keyboard

I keep getting this error message:

```
"'Keyboard' not found. Does your sketch include the line '#include <Keyboard.h>'?"
```

... when I have already included `Keyboard.h`.

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup() {
  pinMode(3,INPUT_PULLUP); 
  pinMode(4,INPUT_PULLUP);

 Serial.begin(9600);    //begin seral comms for debugging
}

void loop() {
  Keyboard.begin();
  if (digitalRead(3) == 0) //if button 3 is pushed
   {
Keyboard.write('z');
delay(200);
}
   else if (digitalRead(4) == 0) //if button 3 is pushed
{
  Keyboard.write('x');
  delay(200);
}
  Keyboard.end();
}
```

`Keyboard.h` is already included as a default library in Arduino so I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: Which Arduino do you have? Please tag your question with that information.

Comment: Please update your question, stating *which* processor and/or board you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have **Arduino/Genuino Uno** selected as your board in the **Tools ► Board ►** menu, then you get the error. If you select **Arduino Leonardo** it compiles correctly.

From [Can't seem to be able use Keyboard.h library](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=346139.0), [this post](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=346139.msg2386530#msg2386530) states:

> Keyboard.h (and Mouse.h) only works on devices that use the ATmega32u4 processor, like the Leonardo or Micro.  See: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard

[This solution](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=346139.msg3671683#msg3671683) might help though

> I had the same problem using Flora
>
> This worked for me:
>
> 1. Tools > Boards > Boards Manager
> 2. Install TeeOnArdu (Then select that board from Boards Manager)
> 3. Tools > USB Type > Serial, Keyboard, Mouse < Joypad
> 4. Upload and run code again (might need to restart IDE)

Comment: Great... btw, what Arduino board do you have?

Comment: was using a pro micro, it is detected as an arduino leonardo same chip i guess