# Keyboard.h not found on Arduino nano

Tags: arduino-nano, keyboard

I am trying to use keyboard on my Arduino nano, but i get this error:

```
'Keyboard' not found. Does your sketch include the line '#include <Keyboard.h>'?
```

As per the answer in [Keyboard.h not found](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/57581/keyboard-h-not-found), I tried change the board to **Arduino Leonardo**, even though the script gets compiled it doesn't get uploaded (keeps on saying uploading for a long time).

This is the code I use:

```
#include <Keyboard.h> 
void setup() {
  Keyboard.begin();
}
void loop() {
}
```

Comment: If you also change the board itself, it'll work. The Uno has different MCU and it doesn't have physical USB interface in it.

Comment: As said above you cannot use the Keyboard library on the Nano. It just doesn't have the necessary hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the comments into an answer:

You cannot (!) use the `Keyboard` library on the Arduino Uno/Nano/Mini. It needs a native USB interface to configure it as a HID device, but the Uno/Nano/Mini all use the Atmega328p, which doesn't have a native USB interface. These Arduinos use an additional chip on the board which acts as USB-UART-bridge.

You can compile the code for the Leonardo, because it has a native USB interface. But you cannot (!) upload code, which is compiled for the Leonardo, to an Uno/Nano/Mini. Its a completely different chip.

**What to do now:** Get an Arduino board which has a native USB interface, for example the Leonardo or the Micro.